# Vue 3 + Vite after npm run dev not load resource with nginx

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nginx, build, vite

[image: 1]

After i run `npm run build` i have tested my project by nginx, but not load resource as image up.

[image: 2]

What's the problem? How do i set the right path?

Comment: The obvious reason is that nginx is configured incorrectly. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks, I thought the error was due to the vue path, as I read in other posts on the net